# Display WFS (GeoJSON) from GeoServer with OpenLayers on Django

Tags: postgis, geoserver, openlayers-2, geodjango

I want to display point data from PostGis to my Django application. I created WFS service from GeoServer and want to display using OpenLayers. I went through many posts but none of them worked 
My code is
myproject/myapp/templates/map.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/css/ol.css" type="text/css">
    <script src="http://openlayers.org/en/v3.12.1/build/ol.js"></script>
    <style>
header {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;     
}
nav {
    line-height:30px;
    background-color:#eeeeee;
    height:503px;
    width:240px;
    float:left;
    padding:5px;          
}
section {
    width:579px;
    float:left;
    padding:10px;   
    height:494px;
}
footer {
    background-color:black;
    color:white;
    clear:both;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px;         
}
</style>
</head>
    <body onload="init()">
    <header>
    <h2>Plant Functional Types</h2>
    </header>
<nav>
<button type="button" onclick="go()">Actual plant functional type</button> 
<button type="button" >Potential plant functional type</button>
<button type="button" > Plant functional types likely to change</button>
<button type="button" > Upload species data</button>
</nav>

<div id="map" class="map" style="width:1080px; height:512px;float:right;" ></div>

<script>
      var map = new ol.Map({
        layers: [
          new ol.layer.Tile({
            source: new ol.source.OSM()
          })
        ],
        target: 'map',
        view: new ol.View({
          center: [0, 0],
          zoom: 2
        })
      });

       var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({
        format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
        url: function(extent, resolution, projection) {
          return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/PFT/ows?service=WFS&' +
              'version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typename=PFT:PFT_pft_pft&' +
              'maxFeatures=50&'+
              'outputFormat=application%2Fjson' +
              'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
        },

      });
    </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

when I run localhost:8080/pft
only map gets dispalyed. Features are not displayed. Please help!

geoserver log shows this

```
2016-01-06 17:03:02,960 INFO [wfs.json] - about to encode JSON 
2016-01-06 17:03:02,964 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - Request: getServiceInfo    
2016-01-06 17:03:02,966 INFO [geoserver.wfs] - Request: getFeature service = WFS version = 1.1.0 baseUrl = localhost:8080/geoserver query[0]: typeName[0] = {PFT}pft_pft maxFeatures = 50 outputFormat = application/json resultType = results
```

Comment: what is in the geoserver log? what shows up in the response from GeoServer? what exactly is sent to GeoServer?

Answer (score 1):

You are not adding `vectorSource` to the map. Are you?

Review the [OL3 WFS](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.13.1/examples/vector-wfs.html) example. Change the url to use your server `http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs` and your layer `PFT:PFT_pft_pft`.

It should look like:

```
    var vectorSource = new ol.layer.Vector({
        source:  new ol.source.Vector({
            format: new ol.format.GeoJSON(),
            url: function (extent) {
                return 'http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&' +
                        'version=1.1.0&request=GetFeature&typename=PFT:PFT_pft_pft&' +
                        'outputFormat=application/json&srsname=EPSG:3857&' +
                        'bbox=' + extent.join(',') + ',EPSG:3857';
            },
            strategy: ol.loadingstrategy.tile(ol.tilegrid.createXYZ())
        })
    });
```

Then add it to the map:

```
map.addLayer(vectorSource);
```

Afterwards, use the browser's developer tools to check out the requests to the server (check the network requests). Check the response of your WFS requests.